# how to use recursion to deal with Fibonacci?

Tags: fibonacci

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n–1)+fib(n–2)
```

I saw the code in the book, but this code has a bug below,
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

`return fib(n–1)+fib(n–2)` is wrong because of  your `–` symbol which is not a valid ASCII minus character

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file main.py on line 5, but
>   no encoding declared;

Your `–` is a `\xe2` character.

Replace it by a normal minus and it'll work

```
def fib(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
```